# Making a scatter plot with string in x axis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two columns: genres (more than 10 unique) and price and I want to compare them using scatter plot.
How can I write string names in x axis?

*price  2.99 3.54 7.00 and so on*

*genre   fiction drama psychology and so on*

Another option: convert string to category and somehow convert category numbers to string during graphing. Is it possible?

```
df['genre'] = df['genre'].astype("category").cat.codes 
Plot = df.plot.scatter(x='genre',
                      y='price',
                      c='DarkBlue')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the genre column as `object`, aka string, Dtype in pandas and plot it. Try running just the line below.

```
df.plot.scatter(x='genre', y='price', c='DarkBlue')
```

Here is a working example.

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

iris.plot.scatter("species", "sepal_length")
```

Comment: No, it says: "scatter requires x column to be numeric"

Comment: @Ksenia: what version of Pandas are you on? This works for me on 1.0.3.

Comment: @mechanical_meat: I have the 1.0.1. Maybe that's a problem.

Comment: I think this is the bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18755

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about axis labels?

if so it's as simple as this

```
plot.xlabel("Genre")
```